# Execute a function from a view in custom component element

Tags: ionic3, components

I have created a custom component in Ionic3. This component is an `ion-card` with his card-header and an ion-list with some items.

I'd like to call a view function when card-header (part of the custom component) is clicked.

I mean, I have my View home.ts / home.html where I load my component custom-component (which is an ion-card with an ion-card-header). I need when the user clicks on ion-card-header call a function declared on home.ts.

Maybe I'm trying to do some weird.

UPDATED:
This is my component (card-parte) and my view (Home).

```
<ion-card>
 <ion-card-header text-center text-wrap>
  {{parte.fechaFormato}} - {{parte.numero}} / {{parte.ejercicio}} 
 </ion-card-header>

 <ion-list>
    <ion-item text-wrap>
      <ion-icon name="contact" item-start></ion-icon>
      {{parte.cliente_empresa}}
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Then I use it in my view Home.html

```
<ion-content>
 <span *ngIf="!nohaytareas">
 <ion-item *ngFor="let parte of datos">
  <card-parte [parte]="parte" ></card-parte>
 </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

In my Home.ts I have for example this function

```
test(parte){
  loadParte(parte);
}
```

I'd like when I click on the component card-parte (in card-header), it call to test()

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Comment: edited with my code @saperlipopette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger a function on the click on the header of your component, simply add the `(click)` directive

```
<ion-card-header text-center text-wrap (click)="yourFunction()">
  {{parte.fechaFormato}} - {{parte.numero}} / {{parte.ejercicio}} 
</ion-card-header>
```

Just add the declaration of `yourFunction()` in the ts file or your component and trigger an event

```
yourFunction(){
  // You can pass custom data with the last argument
  this.events.publish('headerclicked', {});
}
```

From your home.ts subscribe to this event in the constructor :

```
events.subscribe('headerclicked', (data) => {
    // You can retrive your data
    // Here you can open your view
});
```

Comment: If I do this then I'll execute a function declared y card-parte.ts but I need to execute a funcition declared in home.ts

Comment: See my edit about the use of events : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/